# 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)

Tags: mysql, denwer

Вновь эта ошибка. Помогите

Ошибка
Ответ MySQL: Документация

> 1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
>
> phpMyAdmin не смог установить соединение с сервером MySQL. Проверьте
>   хост, имя пользователя и пароль установленные в конфигурационном файле
>   config.inc.php и удостоверьтесь, что они соответствуют данным
>   полученным от администратора сервера MySQL.*

`denwer / mysql`
Проверял строки в `config.inc.php` ,все равно не смог исправить

Comment: ну так смотри создан ли пользователь, правильный ли пароль, что в конфигах сайта прописано

Answer (score 2):

```
'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)
```

Пытаетсь подключится из под рута. У рута всегда есть пароль, но попытка подключения происходит без пароля.

Comment: У меня на денвере нет пароля для рута (это про "всегда")

Comment: Этот коммент заставил меня погуглить что же такое денвер... мой мир никогда не будет прежним :)

Comment: Спасибо, очень помогло, прописал sudo mysql -u root -p и вошло, а в руководстве от хостера написано просто sudo mysql